# Is there a way to extract individual values from a varchar column using SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, string, split

I am trying to extract individual dates from a varchar column in a SQL Server 2016 tablet that are stored comma separated and am not sure how to proceed.  The data is setup like this:

```
article            Consolidation_Order_Cut_Off_Final_Allocation
------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
011040             01/13/2021,03/10/2021
019099             01/13/2021,01/27/2021,02/24/2021,03/24/2021,04/28/2021,05/26/2021,06/23/2021,07/28/2021
019310             01/27/2021,02/03/2021,03/10/2021,04/14/2021,05/12/2021,06/09/2021,07/14/2021,08/11/2021
059611             01/13/2021
```

Ideally - I would have each date split out into a new row.  I have seen a few similar questions that use very complex functions but those seem to be for SQL Server 2008.  I have also found the new function `STRING_SPLIT` but that would seem to be table valued and thus have to come in the `FROM`.  One thought I had was to declare a variable to hold this column and then use something like `select * FROM  string_split(@dates,',');` however since there is more than one value in that list that returns an error.  I am very new to the 2016 version of SQL Server and curious if anyone has ran into a way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String_Split() is a table valued function, so you can call it with a CROSS APPLY

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=bc766b5881e4ce4e021af2f4d4bd547e)**

```
Select A.article
      ,B.Value
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply string_split(Consolidation_Order_Cut_Off_Final_Allocation,',') B
```